# Possible to disable javascript within a xul:browser element (firefox extension)?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I need to render user submitted html within an xul:panel. I'm inserting the html into an xul:browser element within the panel so that invalid xhtml is not an issue (it's sandboxed within the browser frame).

Is there anyway to disable javascript within the xul:browser? My original plan was to write some regex that strips out all JS from the html, but it would be so much easier if I could simply disable JS and not worry about it.

EDIT: Well, browser.docShell.allowJavascript = false; is what I was looking for. Unfortunately this only works if the browser type is set to "content", and if I set a type to "content" xul:browser doesn't render correctly within a panel (known firefox bug that has been around for years). Without a content type it gives the loaded page access to CHROME, which is the reason I wanted to disable JS in the first place.. ugh

Comment: You *must* use type="content" or type="content-primary" on the browser when you're putting random data in it. What's the bug #?

Comment: Nickolay, here is the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=130078

I'm NOT setting a type, but I am filtering out scripts and other things with: Components.classes["@mozilla.org/feed-unescapehtml;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML).parseFragment() -- Which is discussed here: http://adblockplus.org/blog/displaying-web-content-in-an-extension-without-security-issues

Comment: I'd be interesting in knowing if you think this covers any potential vulnerabilities. I'm also intercepting all link clicks and opening them in a new tab.. which prevents linking to a new page that does have malicious js that would access the chrome.